# ssl.c:510: error:14090086:SSL routines:SSL3_GET_SERVER_CERTIFICATE:certificate verify failed

Tags: linux, python-2.7, robotframework, ubuntu-14.04, robotframework-ide

I am getting this error while installing Robot framework (RIDE) in Ubuntu

```
[Errno 1] _ssl.c:510: error:14090086:SSL routines:SSL3_GET_SERVER_CERTIFICATE:certificate verify failed"
```

- Python version: 2.7
- `pip` version: 9.0.1
- Ubuntu version: 14.04

---

```
Exception:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/basecommand.py", line 215, in main
    status = self.run(options, args)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/commands/install.py", line 324, in run
    requirement_set.prepare_files(finder)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/req/req_set.py", line 380, in prepare_files
    ignore_dependencies=self.ignore_dependencies))
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/req/req_set.py", line 620, in _prepare_file
    session=self.session, hashes=hashes)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/download.py", line 821, in unpack_url
    hashes=hashes
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/download.py", line 659, in unpack_http_url
    hashes)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/download.py", line 853, in _download_http_url
    stream=True,
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/_vendor/requests/sessions.py", line 488, in get
    return self.request('GET', url, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/download.py", line 386, in request
    return super(PipSession, self).request(method, url, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/_vendor/requests/sessions.py", line 475, in request
    resp = self.send(prep, **send_kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/_vendor/requests/sessions.py", line 596, in send
    r = adapter.send(request, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/_vendor/cachecontrol/adapter.py", line 47, in send
    resp = super(CacheControlAdapter, self).send(request, **kw)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/_vendor/requests/adapters.py", line 497, in send
    raise SSLError(e, request=request)
SSLError: [Errno 1] _ssl.c:510: error:14090086:SSL routines:SSL3_GET_SERVER_CERTIFICATE:certificate verify failed
You are using pip version 9.0.1, however version 20.2.3 is available.
You should consider upgrading via the 'pip install --upgrade pip' command.
gfi@gfi:/$ sudo python -m pip install pyopenssl pyasn1 ndg-httpsclient
The directory '/home/gfi/.cache/pip/http' or its parent directory is not owned by the current user and the cache has been disabled. Please check the permissions and owner of that directory. If executing pip with sudo, you may want sudo's -H flag.
The directory '/home/gfi/.cache/pip' or its parent directory is not owned by the current user and caching wheels has been disabled. check the permissions and owner of that directory. If executing pip with sudo, you may want sudo's -H flag.
Requirement already satisfied: pyopenssl in /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages
Collecting pyasn1
/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/_vendor/requests/packages/urllib3/util/ssl_.py:318: SNIMissingWarning: An HTTPS request has been made, but the SNI (Subject Name Indication) extension to TLS is not available on this platform. This may cause the server to present an incorrect TLS certificate, which can cause validation failures. You can upgrade to a newer version of Python to solve this. For more information, see https://urllib3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/security.html#snimissingwarning.
  SNIMissingWarning
/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/_vendor/requests/packages/urllib3/util/ssl_.py:122: InsecurePlatformWarning: A true SSLContext object is not available. This prevents urllib3 from configuring SSL appropriately and may cause certain SSL connections to fail. You can upgrade to a newer version of Python to solve this. For more information, see https://urllib3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/security.html#insecureplatformwarning.
  InsecurePlatformWarning
/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/_vendor/requests/packages/urllib3/util/ssl_.py:122: InsecurePlatformWarning: A true SSLContext object is not available. This prevents urllib3 from configuring SSL appropriately and may cause certain SSL connections to fail. You can upgrade to a newer version of Python to solve this. For more information, see https://urllib3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/security.html#insecureplatformwarning.
  InsecurePlatformWarning
/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/_vendor/requests/packages/urllib3/util/ssl_.py:122: InsecurePlatformWarning: A true SSLContext object is not available. This prevents urllib3 from configuring SSL appropriately and may cause certain SSL connections to fail. You can upgrade to a newer version of Python to solve this. For more information, see https://urllib3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/security.html#insecureplatformwarning.
  InsecurePlatformWarning
Exception:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/basecommand.py", line 215, in main
    status = self.run(options, args)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/commands/install.py", line 324, in run
    requirement_set.prepare_files(finder)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/req/req_set.py", line 380, in prepare_files
    ignore_dependencies=self.ignore_dependencies))
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/req/req_set.py", line 620, in _prepare_file
    session=self.session, hashes=hashes)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/download.py", line 821, in unpack_url
    hashes=hashes
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/download.py", line 659, in unpack_http_url
    hashes)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/download.py", line 853, in _download_http_url
    stream=True,
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/_vendor/requests/sessions.py", line 488, in get
    return self.request('GET', url, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/download.py", line 386, in request
    return super(PipSession, self).request(method, url, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/_vendor/requests/sessions.py", line 475, in request
    resp = self.send(prep, **send_kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/_vendor/requests/sessions.py", line 596, in send
    r = adapter.send(request, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/_vendor/cachecontrol/adapter.py", line 47, in send
    resp = super(CacheControlAdapter, self).send(request, **kw)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/_vendor/requests/adapters.py", line 497, in send
    raise SSLError(e, request=request)
SSLError: [Errno 1] _ssl.c:510: error:14090086:SSL routines:SSL3_GET_SERVER_CERTIFICATE:certificate verify failed
You are using pip version 9.0.1, however version 20.2.3 is available.
You should consider upgrading via the 'pip install --upgrade pip' command.
```

i used command "sudo pip install --upgrade pip" still it is coming .
can someone help how to solve SSL certificate failed

Answer (score 2):

The versions you are using are so old that even the update command does not work.
You should not use Python 2.7, because it does not have support (including security fixes).

The new command to update `pip` is:

```
sudo python -m pip install --upgrade pip
```

If that still not solve, then I recommend to install a newer Python 3, even better would be to use latest Ubuntu LTS version.